# Click with Excel-VBA IE drop down button (SPAN NG-IF) (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, vba, excel, internet-explorer

Is it even possible to "click" button if it is SPAN NG-IF?
Or am I looking at it all wrong. That name "Lõuna port" changes if I click on something else on drop down menu. I have list with all the names but can't figure out how to click on any of them. TIA!!!

```
<button class="dropdown-toggle button ico-marina" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" ng-class="{ 'ico-marina': vm.
UserService.getActiveRole().role.authItem === vm.ENUM.ROLE_MARINA_MANAGER || vm.UserService.getActiveRole().role.authItem === vm.ENUM.RO
LE_MARINA_USER, 'ico-vessel': vm.UserService.getActiveRole().role.authItem === vm.ENUM.ROLE_SAILOR}" uib-dropdown-toggle="">
<!-- ngIf: vm.UserService.getActiveRole().role.authItem === vm.ENUM.ROLE_MARINA_MANAGER || vm.UserService.getActiveRole().role.authIte
m === vm.ENUM.ROLE_MARINA_USER -->
<span class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="vm.UserService.getActiveRole().role.authItem === vm.ENUM.ROLE_MARINA_MANAGER || vm.UserServic
e.getActiveRole().role.authItem === vm.ENUM.ROLE_MARINA_USER">Lõunaranna port</span>
<!-- end ngIf: vm.UserService.getActiveRole().role.authItem === vm.ENUM.ROLE_MARINA_MANAGER || vm.UserService.getActiveRole().role.aut
hItem === vm.ENUM.ROLE_MARINA_USER -->
<!-- ngIf: vm.UserService.getActiveRole().role.authItem === vm.ENUM.ROLE_SAILOR -->
<!-- ngIf: vm.UserService.getActiveRole().role.authItem === vm.ENUM.ROLE_ADMIN -->             
<!-- ngIf: vm.UserService.roles.length > 1 -->
<span class="caret ng-scope" ng-if="vm.UserService.roles.length > 1"></span>
<!-- end ngIf: vm.UserService.roles.length > 1 -->          
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
For Each e In oIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If InStr(e.InnerText, cl) <> 0 Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
Next cl
```